# How To Remove Tabwidget oF A TabHost Temporarily?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost, tabwidget, activitygroup

I am developing an app where i used TabHost. Inside my TabHost, there are four tabs. Each tab has its own ActivityGroup. Now, what i want is, in a Acitivty inside one of my ActivityGroup under a tab, i want to remove the Tabwidget temporarily so that the frameLayout will be visible through entire screen of the device. Then, when the activity switch to another activity, the Tabwidget will re-appear on the screen. So the first question is, can i do this? If then, how can i do that? If not possible, then is it possible to switch between a normal activity and an activity inside ActivityGroup under a tab of Tabwidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StartActivity()` works inside `ActivityGroup` also  .
so activity will start in complete screen and `finish();` will send back to `ActivityGroup()` .

Answer (score 1):

For tab at the bottom:

```
public void hideTab()
{
    TabWidget tabwidget=getTabWidget();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)tabwidget.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, -100);

}
public void showTab()
{
    TabWidget tabwidget=getTabWidget();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)tabwidget.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, -3);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `TabWiget` is a subclass of `View` you should be able to hide/reshow it using `setVisibility()`.

You would need a reference to your TabWidget - where this reference needs to be, depends on what class will handle hide/show. In my example below I will assume you put the functionality in your `TabActivity` - so there we add two methods and a reference to the `TabWidget`:

```
TabWidget myTabWidget; //You will need to find it in the layout in onCreate using findViewById( R.id.idOfYourTabWidget ).

public void hideTabs() {
  myTabWidget.setVisibility( View.GONE );
}

public void showTabs() {
  myTabWidget.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
}
```

Then in the `Activity` that needs to hide the tabs you will need to do something like:

```
Activity activity = getParent(); //Might be getParent().getParent(); if you're inside an ActivityGroup.
if( activity instanceof MyTabActivity ) //Just to make sure.
  ((MyTabActivity) activity).hideTabs();
```

And to reshow the tabs, the same thing but calling `((MyTabActivity) activity).showTabs();` instead.

Comment: Well , I have done something like that before asking this question. But the problem is, though the Tabwidget become invisible, the space of the Tabwidget remains blank, The FrameLayout doesn't cover the whole screen. What i want, when the Tabwidget will be removed temporarily, The FrameLayout will be shown through entire screen.